# Vector of vector as data member for class is not recognized

Tags: c++, class, vector

When I have compositions of vectors as class data members,

```
classobj(std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix)
```

they are not recognized as valid argument lists. For example, when I write

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> exammatrix
classobj(exammatrix)
```

for vector of vector I get the error: "No instance of constructor matching the argument type:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>>>"
```

which is really the same as `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`.

Here is a simple example of the problem (my compiler is VS15):

```
#include <vector>

class ELclass {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>> CellX;
public:
    ELclass(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>> xCellX) : CellX(xCellX) {}

};

int main() {

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>> CellX;

    ELclass Eli(CellX);

}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error you are getting?

Comment: No instance of constructor matching the argument list: std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>>>

Comment: Works for me (https://ideone.com/UoswA9)

Comment: alright, I will check again if there is sth else wrong bc it doesn't work for me. Thanks guys.

Comment: Type alias would help your code.